# bind can be composed of fmap and join, so do we have to use monadic functions a -> m b?

Tags: haskell, math, functional-programming, monads, functor

I don't use Haskell a lot, but I understand the concept of Monads.

I had been confused by [Kleisli triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleisli_category#Extension_operators_and_Kleisli_triples), and the category, however,

[fmap and join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#fmap_and_join)

> Although Haskell defines monads in terms of the return and bind functions, it is also possible to define a monad in terms of `return` and two other operations, `join` and `fmap`. This formulation fits more closely with the original definition of monads in category theory. The `fmap` operation, with type `(t → u) → M t → M u`, takes a function between two types and produces a function that does the "same thing" to values in the monad. The `join` operation, with type `M (M t) → M t`, "flattens" two layers of monadic information into one.

helps me to the background principle of Monads.

> The two formulations are related as follows:

```
fmap f m = m >>= (return . f)
join n   = n >>= id

fmap :: (a -> b) -> (m a -> m b)
unit :: a -> m a
join :: m (m a) -> m a
>>=  :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

m >>= f  =  join $ fmap f m
```

My question is:
I think that since `>>=`  can be composed of `fmap` and `join`, a monadic function 
`a -> m b` is not required and normal functions `a -> b` will satisfy the operation, but so many tutorials around the web still insist to use a monadic functions since that is the Kleisli triple and the monad-laws.

Well, shouldn't we just use non-monadic functions, as long as they are endo-functions, for the simplicity? What do I miss?

Related topics are

[Monad join function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382210/monad-join-function)

[Haskell Monad bind operator confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975022/haskell-monad-bind-operator-confusion)

[Difference in capability between fmap and bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387237/difference-in-capability-between-fmap-and-bind)

Comment: Since the equivalence between these two forms is already clear to you, try rewriting some example code using `>>=` and `return` to use `fmap` and `join` instead. Is the result clearer? Does it use less "monadic functions"? If so, then include such a sample in your question, to make it clearer what you wish could happen; if not, then you have your answer as to why it is not often done. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/35387237/625403,

Comment: Actually, I did, in JavaScript. It is clear to me that to make the code work in monadic way without monadic functions, all we have to do is create the composed bind with fmap*joint. The reason I don't put sample is I don't want make this topic limited to JavaScript and some concrete example.

Comment: I don't understand your point. Whay do you mean with "a monadic function `a -> m a` is not required? With only `fmap,join,>>=` you can not define `return`. Indeed, `return` is the only primitive that lets us create a monadic value from a non-monadic value. If you prefer, I think you could replace `return :: a -> m a` with `base :: m ()` satisfying a bunch of laws, and then have `return x = fmap (const x) base`.

Comment: I believe the types should be `return :: a -> m a` (not `unit`), `fmap :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`, and `(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. (With the requirement  `Monad m`.) If you get the types wrong, none of it makes any sense.

Comment: @chi , sorry it is obviously a typo and I modified it. It's `a -> m b` the nomadic function, not unit/return  `a -> m a`.

Comment: @molbdnilo same, it was a typo. I didn't mean that of course.

Comment: short answer: your quoted text itself talks about `return` which is a "monadic function" in your terminology. So no, you can't do without it. also, `a -> b` is *not* the type of endofunctions (that would be `a -> a` only).

Comment: What is the type of `readIORef` in your proposed alternate world? Is it an `a -> m b` function or an `a -> b` function? If an `a -> m b` function, is this suitable motivation for having `a -> m b` functions (it certainly is for me)? If not, why not?

Comment: @WillNess I think your answer is irrelevant because you merely could mention terminology issue. I think I made the things clear showing mathematical structure. Please do not make the topic confusing with playing words.

Comment: @bayesian-study I think there’s is a misunderstanding here related to the nature of Haskell’s polymorphism and that it is causing miscommunication. I think Daniel Wagner’s last comment could help clarify this.

Comment: repeat quote, *"it is also possible to define a monad in terms of `return` and two other operations, `join` and `fmap`"*. IOW *three* functions are needed, not two, specifically the `return :: (Monad m) => a -> m a`. this is also mentioned in the answer below which is from one of the leading scientists in the field. for any function `f :: a -> b` we have `(return . f) :: (Monad m) => a -> m b`. moreover, opaque types like `IO` which the user doesn't have access to the definition of, inevitably must provide some primitives with such signature as well, like e.g. `putStr :: String -> IO ()`.

Comment: What do you mean by, _"a monadic function  `a -> m b` is not required and normal functions `a -> b` will satisfy the operation"_? You also said that, _"It is clear to me that to make the code work in monadic way without monadic functions, all we have to do is create the composed bind with fmap*joint. The reason I don't put sample is I don't want make this topic limited to JavaScript and some concrete example."_ Why don't you share the code example? It would be really helpful for us to understand what you're trying to convey.

Comment: @AaditMShah Hi, I'm really glad you've joined this topic, and eventually, I think you are the one to deserve the 500point bounty contribution. I will edit my Question, and let you know when it's done. Currently, not enough time to write, so. Just greeting.

Comment: You should accept one of the two answers provided and @KenOKABE should award them the bounty because both of them are absolutely correct.

Comment: @AaditMShah No, pigworker understand the problem and he answered in that context, however, DarthFennec doesn't know the real Monad concept and looking at you supporting the answer as absolute correctness neither do you.

Comment: I answered by myself and it's so disappointing to see very few knows what's the real problem is.

Comment: @AaditMShah and just let you know, I downvote you guys simply because your understanding is not enough, and spreading a wrong idea. If you downvote my answer, just clarify reason, and you are welcome to discuss your justification of conduct.

Answer (score 10):

In a sense, you're right. As every monad `m` is a functor, we can use `fmap f` with a function `f :: a -> b` to turn an `m a` into an `m b`, but there's a catch. What's `b`?

I like to think of such an `m` as meaning "plan-to-get", where "plans" involve some sort of additional interaction beyond pure computation. If you have a "plan-to-get `Int`" and you want a "plan-to-get `String`", you can use `fmap` with a function in `Int -> String`, but the type of that function tells you that getting the `String` from the `Int` involves no further interaction.

That isn't always so: perhaps the `Int` is a student registration number and the `String` is their name, so the plan to convert from one to the other needs an external lookup in some table. Then I don't have a pure function from `Int` to `String`, but rather a pure function from `Int` to "plan-to-get `String`". If I `fmap` that across my "plan-to-get `Int`", that's fine, but I end up with "plan-to-get (plan-to-get `String`)" and I need to `join` the outer and inner plans.

The general situation is that we have enough information to compute the plan to get more. That's what `a -> m b` models. In particular, we have `return :: a -> m a`, which turns the information we have into the plan that gives us exactly that information by taking no further action, and we have `(>=>) :: (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> m c)` which composes two such things. We also have that `(>=>)` is associative and absorbs `return` on left and right, much the way `;` is associative and absorbs `skip` in classic imperative programming.

It's more convenient to build larger plans from smaller ones using this compositional approach, keeping the number of "plan-to-get" layers a consistent *one*. Otherwise, you need to build up an *n*-layer plan with `fmap`, then do the right number of `join`s on the outside (which will be a brittle property of the plan).

Now, as Haskell is a language with a concept of "free variable" and "scope", the `a` in

```
(>=>) :: (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> m c)
```

representing the "overall input information" can just be taken to come from the scope of things we already have, leaving

```
(>>=) ::       m b  -> (b -> m c) ->       m c
```

and we get back "bind", which is the tool that presents the compositional structure in the most programmer-friendly form, resembling a local definition.

To sum up, you can work with `a -> b`, but often you need `b` to be "plan-to-get something", and that's the helpful thing to choose if you want to build plans compositionally.

Comment: Thanks for your thought. How about an issue of compatibility? To me, it's obvious there are many endo-functions type libraries, for instance Math libraries are endo-functions. If we simply can use `a -> b`,  we don't use much brain to take advantage of them to monadic context, but in the situation `a -> m b` is  required, "oops, I forgot make to convert that and that" confusion must arise.

Comment: @bayesian-study In math, it common for functions to be total, thus you see a lot of `a -> b` function signatures. `a -> m b` arises when there a computations which have other effects. For example, if we model division, we have an edge case where we might fail when the denominator is 0. One way to model this is with a `Maybe` type: `divide :: a -> Maybe b`.

Comment: Given that `a -> m c` is a special case of `a -> b`, a lot of that material is highly reusable. Moreover, if you have a pure `f :: a -> b`, then `(return . f) :: a -> m b` is the extra bit of plumbing you need. What you don't get to do is give `Int -> m String` things the type `Int -> String`, because that would be a serious lie. So yes, the setup does require a bit of extra plumbing to put the extra `m`s where they're needed, and it does cause some confusion. Some people (e.g., me) advocate a cleaner separation of the notions of value and effect. NB I didn't pay to be asked this question!

Comment: @pigworker Interesting perceptive, however, the type thing you insist is also tricky and to be carefully, because if your mind set is `Int -> m String`, why don't you define a special type `Int String`? then it becomes endo  `Int String a  ->  Int String b`. I still don't see much justifications we must stick to `a -> m b` because, as you say `a -> m c` is a special case of `a -> b`, why not the matter generalized??

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov I can't agree to your opinion that "something will fail" by using more generalized form `a -> b` not the special form `a -> m b`. I would agree if you mention the opposite, obviously.

Comment: @bayesian-study How would you represent a division by 0 with the signature `a -> b`? Can I always compute `b` for any `a`?

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov Simply I define a type of `mb`. and the endofuction is `mb a -> mb b`  That is what we want right?

Comment: Well, I'm basically a heavy JavaScript guy from duck-typing world, and not bothered by static-typing around. I simply feel something wrong to limit the type behavior in advance of writing code. You guys are quite right if you strongly feel the type`m` gives you a "free hand", your mind set is duck-typing not static. Welcome to duck-typing world.  It's definitely not a problem of generalized `a -> b` endo-functions!

Comment: @bayesian-study Not sure I follow your train of thought. What is `mb` to you in this context? Can you give a concrete example? How would you model the example I provided with division?

Comment: `mb` would model a `Maybe a` in this case? What value would represent the absence of a result in the codomain?

Comment: What would this type `Int String` mean? It couldn't be called `Int String` because `Int` and `String` are already types. And why would a special type be a good idea if the point is to achieve *appropriate* generality? Suppose I want to convert back from a name to a registration number? That'll need a `String -> m Int` for *the same* `m` but different value types. The point is to indicate what sorts of *interaction plans* are allowed, independently of the types of value to be computed by means of those plans, and allowing plans to be constructed compositionally.

Comment: The comments are deleted for some reason, so I must re-post an important fact. `Maybe a` has absolutely no relation with `a -> m b`. There is "Maybe Monoids".

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I also should have mentioned the fact there is `fmap` of Maybe "Maybe Functor" http://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/03/26/the-maybe-functor/

Comment: @pigworker I'm from duck-typing world, so please excuse me to explain the duck-typing oriented idea in JavaScript. It is simply as follows:

Comment: In JS, `Number('123') =123`, also `Number(Number) = Number`

Comment: Obviously, this corresponds to `unit :: a -> m a` and `join :: m (m a) -> m a`

Comment: If you add `fmap :: (a -> b) -> (m a -> m b)` method to `Number` object/function prototype, the pair of object ad method of `Number` becomes a monad.

Comment: In this Monad scheme, I can't see any justification to give an extra space for the fancy `a -> mb`.

Comment: In a sense, Number type is a natural born Monad, `1 = (1) = ((1))`  because it embraces the built-in structure of `join` or flatten, no need to give foregin natures later. You can chain `map` of `fmap` to the numbers. Nobody don't `bind` between numbers.

Comment: So, the whole point is "how to obtain a type of fractal structure line Number, from any other types?" right? Moggi or Philip Wadler chosed Kleisli-category and `bind`  `a - mb`  which is fine, but I simply feel wrong to stick to it. It's just a historical reason.

Comment: @KenOKABE I am confused. Are you reposting your own comments that got deleted or someone else’s comments? Also, there are a lot of things to unpack and discuss from those comments. I believe there are at least one or two misunderstandings that are obscuring things.

Comment: @DavidYoung No, I have repost an important reference deleted along with some off-topic controversy, and please do not repeat to transform the topic to communication staff. If you insist, just email me kenokabe@gmail.com

Comment: @KenOKABE I’m afraid I don’t understand what you mean, but I hope this discussion ends up working out well for everyone. Maybe the SO chat would be a better venue for it though?

Comment: @pigworker would this *"cleaner separation of the notions of value and effect"* mean replacing the EDSLs (which the monads are), with some kind of syntax-based DSL? what would replace `putStr`, for instance?

Comment: @WillNess Why ask "do you mean X?" when you could just ask what I mean? Alternatively, you could read my POPL 2017 paper, ungooglably named "Do Be Do Be Do", where I say what I mean.

Answer (score 8):

I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding what your question actually is, but I'll take a crack at it anyway.

> I think that since `>>=` can be composed of `fmap` and `join`, a monadic function  `a -> m b` is not required and normal functions `a -> b` will satisfy the operation,

I expect you're referring to the "monadic function `a -> m b`" in the type for `>>=`, is that correct? Well, let's see what happens when we replace that with a function of type `a -> b`:

```
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b  -- standard version
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> b) -> m b    -- your version
```

But doesn't this look familiar? It's equivalent to `fmap :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`, but with the parameters switched. In fact, the implementation is just `x >>= y = fmap y x`, no need for `join`. So there's your answer: if you use a "normal function `a -> b`" instead of a "monadic function `a -> m b`", you *no longer have a monad*. Instead, you have a `Functor`.

---

> but so many tutorials around the web still insist to use a monadic functions since that is the Kleisli triple and the monad-laws.

I'm not sure which tutorials you're looking at. In my experience, the nature of tutorials is that they insist on whatever they're a tutorial for. It would be weird if a tutorial for `Monad`s started presenting problems, and then suggesting things other than `Monad`s as solutions; at the very least, that would be out of the tutorial's scope, and a waste of time for anyone reading it to learn about `Monad`s.

---

> Well, shouldn't we just use non-monadic functions, as long as they are endo-functions, for the simplicity? What do I miss?

Endofunctions are functions of type `a -> a`. Given the context of your question, I think you actually mean *pure functions* of type `a -> b` ("pure" as opposed to inherently monadic functions such as `readIORef` that need to be type `a -> m b`). If my assumption is wrong, let me know, and I'll edit the question.

EDIT:
As suggested in a comment by @duplode, it's likely that you mean *endofunctor*, which in Haskell is just any type of `Functor`. In this case, the below still applies.

In situations where `Monad` isn't necessary, it is often simpler to use `Applicative`, `Functor`, or just basic pure functions. In these cases, these things should be (and generally are) used in place of a `Monad`. For example:

```
ws <- getLine >>= return . words  -- Monad
ws <- words <$> getLine           -- Functor (much nicer)
```

To be clear: If it's possible without a monad, and it's simpler and more readable without a monad, then you should do it without a monad! If a monad makes the code more complex or confusing than it needs to be, don't use a monad! Haskell has monads for the sole purpose of making certain complex computations simpler, easier to read, and easier to reason about. If that's not happening, *you shouldn't be using a monad*.

Comment: I feel the OP might be mixing up "endofunctions" with "endofunctors" (as in "a `Functor` is a **Hask** endofunctor"), but that is just a guess.

Comment: @duplode This is very probable. I've edited the answer to include this.

Comment: and just let you know, I downvote you guys simply because your understanding is not enough, and spreading a wrong idea. If you downvote my answer, just clarify reason, and you are welcome to discuss your justification of conduct.

Comment: @user6440264 The reason I'm having a hard time understanding your question is because I can take it about ten wildly varying ways that all make equal amounts of sense. Put another way, the reason my "understanding is not enough" is because *you aren't being clear enough*. I don't think I deserve downvotes for that. I'd have liked for us all to work together and learn from each other (as is ultimately the purpose of this site), and I'm a little disappointed that that hasn't turned out to be possible.

Comment: @DarthFennec https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51376391/revisions ; https://imgur.com/a/SyzZbFw

Comment: @WillNess Why link me the revision history? I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: just some meta stuff there, related to the votes you've received. you can safely disregard all that. :)

Comment: @WillNess Ah, gotcha. I wasn't worried about my votes, I was just disappointed in his behavior. Thanks though ^^

Answer (score 2):

## There is no reason.

> I think that since `>>=` can be composed of `fmap` and `join`, a monadic function `a -> m b` is not required

Yes, you're totally right. We don't need to require `>>=` for a monad, we could also require `join` instead. The two are totally equivalent. As we can also compose `join = (>>= id)`, we can do either

```
class Monad m where
    return :: a -> m a
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
    (=<<) :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
    -- join = (=<<) id
```

or

```
class Monad m where
    return :: a -> m a
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
    join :: m (m a) -> m a
    -- (=<<) = (join .) . fmap
```

It doesn't matter which one we use. Admittedly, the latter looks simpler because there is only one higher-order function (`fmap`), in the former the types of `fmap` and `=<<` look too similar. `join` gives a better idea of what distinguishes a monad from a functor.

## Versatility

We can derive `>>=` from `fmap` and `join`, but we can derive `join` from `>>=` only. In fact, we can even derive `fmap` from `>>=` and `return`. So should we say that `>>=` is more basic than the other? More powerful? Or maybe just: more convoluted?

We would rather like to write

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
implement Functor Maybe where
    fmap = (=<<) . (return .) -- maybe not even write this ourselves
implement Monad Maybe where
    return = Just
    f =<< Just x = f x
    _ =<< Nothing  = Nothing
```

than

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
implement Functor Maybe where
    fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)
    fmap f Nothing  = Nothing
implement Monad Maybe where
    return x = Just x
    join (Just (Just x)) = Just x
    join (Just Nothing)  = Nothing
    join Nothing         = Nothing
```

The former solution using `>>=` is minimal.

## Convenience

> Well, shouldn't we just use non-monadic functions for the simplicity?

No. The whole idea of defining the monad typeclass is to ease working with monadic functions. On their own, the `return`/`fmap`/`join` functions are pretty useless, what we are interested in are other functions that return the monadic data type: `tryParse :: String -> Maybe Int` for example.

And the whole idea behind monads is that we can arbitrarily chain and nest them, getting back a plain type in the end. After having parsed a number, we need to validate the optional result (giving us another optional result) - *in* the monad (`fmap validate`) before getting it back out. There are usually no operations that yield nested data directly, we only get nested monad types because we do further monadic operations inside a monadic type. And we'd much rather write

```
tryRead = (=<<) validate . tryParse
```

than

```
tryRead = join . fmap validate . tryParse
```

That's why `>>=` is more important for using monads in daily life than `join`. I would also guess that having to implement `>>=` directly, rather than implement `join` explicitly and have `>>=` get derived from it, allows for better (easier) compiler optimisations.

Comment: what good is `join` without any function of `Monad m => a -> m b` type? It'd be an applicative then, not a monad. `join [[x+1, x*2] | x <-[10..13]]` is just `pure (&) <*> [10..13] <*> [(+1),(*2)]`. Monad is a *Kleisli* triple, by definition, isn't it? What would replace `print`, for example? Some verbs of a non-pure Monad just have to be supplied as primitives. Not everything is achievable by composition with `pure`, unless that monad itself is *pure*, of course.

Comment: @WillNess Yes, that's exactly what I meant by "*On their own, the `return`/`fmap`/`join` functions are pretty useless*"

Comment: all I saw was, "a monadic function `a -> m b` is not required" --- "Yes, you're totally right."

Comment: @WillNess Oh, right. I understood that as "a monad method `>>=` that takes a monadic function is not required".

Answer (score 0):

Composition of Kleisli arrows a -> [b]

```
 (a->mb) -> (b->mc) -> (a->mc)
    f          g
```

a, b, c are arbitrary types, m is always the same, here it is []

We have to produce a function (a->mc)
Functions are produced with a lambda, we have one argument a.

```
f >=> g =  \a -> ..f..g..
           \a -> let mb = f a;
                 in mc = mb >>= g
```

Above is taken from Bartosz Milewski Category Theory 10.1: Monads

```
mb >>= g producing mc    That looks like a functor

mb >>= b->mc     variable substitution: mc -> c'
mb >>= b->c'     now this is a functor!
fmap b->c' mb     fmap goes under the hood
m (b->c' b)      back substitution c' -> mc
m (b->mc b)
m (mc)    is not mc, so  another try!

join fmap g mb
join m(mc)     Monoid
mc       is mc   OK!

mc = mb >>= g
mc = join $ fmap g mb
```

g is b -> mc, so >>= and join-fmap use it the same way.
If it's not available, you can build it with return.

```
return
If we have b->c instead of b->mc

mb >>= (b->c) -> (b->mc)
         f
mb >>= \b -> let c = f b ;
             mc = return c
             in  mc
return :: c -> mc

mc = mb >>= \b -> return $ f b
and
mc = join $ fmap (\b -> return $ f b) mb
```

f is b -> c, you can use it together with return instead of b -> mc (Your Question).